# Install ttf file in android

Tags: android, fonts, sdl-ttf

I have a ttf file downloaded from firebase. Now I want to apply this file to install fonts for the entire device, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create Folder named **font** in resource (res) folder and paste your fonts.tft file there.

[You can match attach an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Xse.png)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abc_font" />
```

**If you want to set programatically**

```
textView.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.abc_font))
```

Comment: Add this to your app styles:

<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>